Сode in IDA breaks off
My code breaks off, and then the code color is red, like in the screenshot, a fragment of a function. What can you do here? How to restore the code? Is there a keyboard shortcut for this?


It doesn't look like a fragment, it looks like a complete function. Locating cursor at 0x1e2c0 and pressing P will define it as a function and the code will not be red.
This happens because IDA doesn't recognize this code as a function during auto-analysis, and there are multiple possible reasons for that, for example this function is never called directly or the code from which it is called is not recognized as such and thus not disassembled.
